# Short way to write IF Statement + Assignment of Async Function in one line

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider the code

```
let promiseEmployees;
const employeeFlag = DB.GetFromEMPDB(); // Goes to DAL and gets results


if (employeeFlag) {
    promiseEmployees = async () => {
            // Imp
            // ...
            // ...
            // ...
    };
}
```

Is it possible to rewrite this code in one line without writing literally the `if (...) {...}` ?

Comment: That's certainly possible. But why would you want to? It most certainly wont improve readability.

Comment: What's wrong with `if (DB.GetFromEMPDB()) promiseEmployees = async () => {...}`? By the way, `promiseEmployees` won't be a promise with your code anyway, it will be an async function. (It would be a promise if you'd also _call_ the function.)

Answer (score 3):

This should work the following way:

```js
const promiseEmployees = !DB.GetFromEMPDB()
  ? undefined
  : async () => {
      // Imp
    };
```

Comment: This I know , I'm looking for a shorter way...

Comment: How much shorter do you need? You could write no code. That would be shorter.